# Resizing image at client-side using JQuery file upload to amazon S3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, coffeescript

I already saw some examples at the internet like: [**this**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing) and [**this one**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-multiple-resolutions-of-one-image-with-multiple-resize-options), but I'm following the [**RailsCast Episode #383 Uploading to Amazon S3**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3) and at the very end of the video he mentions about resize the image on the client-side using javascript, of course.
The problem is, I can't implement if I follow his example. I'm using the gem [jquery-fileupload-rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails/wiki)

**EDIT**: I noticed I was missing some JS required at the [JQuery-fileupload example to resize image page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing), but still doesn't'work.
My Requires on the **application.js**

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/load-image
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/canvas-to-blob
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require jquery.fileupload-process
//= require jquery.fileupload-image
//= require jquery-fileupload/locale
```

My **posts.js.coffee**
http://pastebin.com/9sm7UtsP

```
jQuery ->
  $('#fileupload').fileupload
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#fileupload').append(data.context)
        data.submit()
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")

    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')

    done: (e, data) ->
      file = data.files[0]
      domain = $('#fileupload').attr('action')
      path = $('#fileupload input[name=key]').val().replace('${filename}', file.name)
      to = $('#fileupload').data('post')
      content = {}
      content[$('#fileupload').data('as')] = domain + path
      $.post(to, content)
      data.context.remove() if data.context # remove progress bar

    fail: (e, data) ->
      alert("#{data.files[0].name} failed to upload.")
      console.log("Upload failed:")
      console.log(data)
```

My **upload_helper.rb** ( path: apps/helpers )
http://pastebin.com/VxAbiUft

```
module UploadHelper
  def s3_uploader_form(options = {}, &block)
    uploader = S3Uploader.new(options)
    form_tag(uploader.url, uploader.form_options) do
      uploader.fields.map do |name, value|
        hidden_field_tag(name, value)
      end.join.html_safe + capture(&block)
    end
  end

  class S3Uploader
    def initialize(options)
      @options = options.reverse_merge(
        id: "fileupload",
        aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
        aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
        bucket: ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"],
        acl: "public-read",
        expiration: 10.hours.from_now,
        max_file_size: 2.megabytes,
        as: "file"
      )
    end

    def form_options
      {
        id: @options[:id],
        method: "post",
        authenticity_token: false,
        multipart: true,
        data: {
          post: @options[:post],
          as: @options[:as]
        }
      }
    end

    def fields
      {
        :key => key,
        :acl => @options[:acl],
        :policy => policy,
        :signature => signature,
        "AWSAccessKeyId" => @options[:aws_access_key_id],
      }
    end

    def key
      @key ||= "uploads/#{SecureRandom.hex}/${filename}"
    end

    def url
      "https://#{@options[:bucket]}.s3.amazonaws.com/"
    end

    def policy
      Base64.encode64(policy_data.to_json).gsub("\n", "")
    end

    def policy_data
      {
        expiration: @options[:expiration],
        conditions: [
          ["starts-with", "$utf8", ""],
          ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
          ["content-length-range", 0, @options[:max_file_size]],
          {bucket: @options[:bucket]},
          {acl: @options[:acl]}
        ]
      }
    end

    def signature
      Base64.encode64(
        OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
          OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'),
          @options[:aws_secret_access_key], policy
        )
      ).gsub("\n", "")
    end
  end
end
```

The **_form.html.erb**: 
http://pastebin.com/Sqk8XK6U

And the **create.js.erb** ( the **@image** variable comes from the controller - I don't thinks its relevant to post the controller logic since its a javascript problem )
http://pastebin.com/BBAGE5Me

So I want to resize the image to create thumbnails before uploads to S3, so I don't waste my storage on the S3 and bandwidth to the client. Any idea?

I already tried to add this respective options to the **posts.js.coffee** script: 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options
But no success was achieved.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you come to any conclusions?

Comment: no... I was on this for 2 weeks and no success, so I had to use the the normal way...  I'm still waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you checked around before, you would've found other similar posts.

It seems that the add callback causes the process function to be ignored so you have to manually call it within the add callback. Also you don't have any options defined for resizing in your code...

I posted a similar question and solved it myself after some playing around:
[Using jquery fileupload with coffeescript - resizing image when using add callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753646/using-jquery-fileupload-with-coffeescript-resizing-image-when-using-add-callba)