# JQuery-File-Upload Client side Image resizing with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-file-upload

I'd like to implement client side image resizing using [Jquery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload):

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing

I'd like to implement it in coffeescript, though, to use with some file uploading code I found from this railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3

I'm not sure how to incorporate the disableImageResize example with coffeescript.  This is what I have, which doesn't work (I can run the app, but it doesn't seem to do any resizing):

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_image').fileupload
    dataType: "script"     
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
            imageMaxWidth: 667,
            imageMaxHeight: 667
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        $('#images').append('<div class="placeholder"></div>');
        $('.placeholder').hide();
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#imageUploadProgress').append(data.context)
        data.submit()       
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
        if progress == 100
           $('.placeholder').show();
           # scroll to the bottom of the thumbGallery to show recently uploaded image
           document.getElementById("images").scrollTop = document.getElementById("images").scrollHeight
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?  I found other StackOverflow questions about the same topic, but both are unanswered:

[How to resize images client side using jquery file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096946/how-to-resize-images-client-side-using-jquery-file-upload)

[Resizing image at client-side using JQuery file upload to amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925700/resizing-image-at-client-side-using-jquery-file-upload-to-amazon-s3)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to remove the add callback.  Otherwise, you're responsible for triggering the resize manually, which I have yet to find out how to do!

Comment: That did the trick - would be nice to keep the add callback however