# Canceling all "jquery file upload" uploads does does not work when using client side resizing

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I am trying to get canceling all uploads to work with client size resizing. I can get one or the other to work, but not both at the same time. I have been maintaining a stack of xhr objects in my `add` method, but that requires calling `data,submit()` directly. I have now changed my code to hook into `fileuploadadd` and the resizing works great, but canceling only cancels one file (I assume the latest one).

This is what it currently looks like:

```
@addFile = (e, data) =>
  if @validate(data)
    this.transfers.push(data)
  else
    $result = $("<div class='error'>#{data.files[0].name} failed to upload. Files must be 5MB or less, and must be gif, jpg, or png format.</div>")
    $messageContainer.append($result)
    e.preventDefault()

$(input).fileupload
  disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/.test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent)
  imageMaxWidth: 1024
  imageMaxHeight: 1024
  imageCrop: false
.bind('fileuploadadd', @addFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dannio and his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22753646/617243) I was able to solve this. Here is what I ended up with and it works great:

```
class Uploader
  transfers: []
  cancelAll: ->
    for xhr in this.transfers
      xhr.abort() if xhr
    this.transfers = []
  configure: (input) ->
    configurator = this

    $(input).fileupload
      disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/.test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent)
      imageMaxWidth: 1024
      imageMaxHeight: 1024
      imageCrop: false
      add: (e, data) =>
        if this.validate(data)
          $target = $(e.target)
          data.process(->
            return $target.fileupload('process', data)
          ).done(->
            configurator.transfers.push data.submit()
          )
  validate: (data) ->
    if typeof data.files[0].type != 'undefined' && data.files[0].size != 'undefined'
      valid = data.files[0].type in ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
      valid && data.files[0].size <= 5242880
    else
      true
```